# Amazon SDK - Temporary Credentials and AssumeRoleRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using version 1.11.79 of the Amazon Java SDK
I have a job that creates a snapshot of all my server volumes.
With sleeps etc (to satisfy Amazon SDK guidelines) - this has started to take over an hour

I use the following code to construct my AmazonEC2Client using temporary credentials

```
        AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(roleARN).withExternalId(externalId).withDurationSeconds(3600)
            .withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName);

    AssumeRoleResult assumeResult = amazonSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRole(assumeRequest);
    Credentials credentials = assumeResult.getCredentials();

    temporaryCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(credentials.getAccessKeyId(), credentials.getSecretAccessKey(), credentials.getSessionToken());

    CustomAmazonCredentialsProviderVO customAmazonCredentialsProviderVO = new CustomAmazonCredentialsProviderVO();
    customAmazonCredentialsProviderVO.setCredentials(temporaryCredentials);
    LOG.debug("customAmazonCredentialsProviderVO:{}", customAmazonCredentialsProviderVO);

    amazonEC2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(customAmazonCredentialsProviderVO, amazonClientConfiguration);
```

The problem is with the AssumeRoleRequest and the withDurationSeconds method - the max you can set it to is 3600 seconds (1 hour)

I need to be able to set this to say 2 or 3 hours

Does anyone know if there is another way to create temporary credentials that will last more than 1 hour?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [GetSessionToken](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html), which accepts the  DurationSeconds value as high as 129600 provided you are an IAM user.

From the docs:

> Credentials that are created by IAM users are valid for the duration that you specify, from 900 seconds (15 minutes) up to a maximum of 129600 seconds (36 hours), with a default of 43200 seconds (12 hours)

Comment: That would be useful but unfortunatelly we are not using IAM as some of the servers we manage are in lots of different amazon accounts

Comment: In that case, I don't think there is any option available to request credentials for more than an hour. You can try to replace the token with a newly generated one on expiry and continue the snapshotting.

Comment: Have you ever used this class - just wondering if and when the refresh method would be called - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.html

Comment: No I have not used it, but from what I read the refresh is called automatically by the credentials provider on expiration, or you can invoke it manually too

Comment: Yeah I tried to implement that class just there now to force the refresh of credentials but as of yet no joy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in control of the role which the job assumes, you can simply set the `MaxSessionDuration` property. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-maxsessionduration) (emphasize mine):

> The maximum session duration (in seconds) for the specified role. **Anyone who uses the AWS CLI or API to assume the role can specify the duration using the optional DurationSeconds API parameter or duration-seconds CLI parameter.** Minimum value of 3600. Maximum value of 43200.

Increasing this limit should allow you to use a value > 3600 in your `AssumeRoleRequest`.

I just tried this using the AWS SDK for .NET, and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who gets to this thread , and want a solution that will make sure the session always lives. you can use the STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider given by the AWS SDK , but notice it will create extra thread to make sure the session is alive . you can also use custom implementation that is not creating extra thread like the below netflix implementation:

https://www.javatips.net/api/SimianArmy-master/src/main/java/com/netflix/simianarmy/aws/STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.java